# Parent-child relation entity to MAP to view model

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, model-view-controller, parent-child

I have location data coming from DB. There is parent-Child Relationship in my Location table.

I retrieved the records. But problem is how can I populate my View Model.

For example

Location 'US' has child 'California' and 'New York', and they have their own child.

I am not using any mapping tool.

Here is the sample data

```
    Id     ChildId   Name
    1      null      US
    2      null      Canada
    3      1         California
    4      3         Los Angeles
    5      2         Nova Scotia
    6      5         Halifax
```

And I dont know the depth of my Location table's parent-Child relation ship

I like some solution so when I write

```
  List<LocVM> obj=context.locations.select(w=new LocVM{....,ChileLocation=w.ChildLoc}).tolist();
```

so my object will have all locations and child locations

View Model

```
  Class LocVM{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public int chileId {get;set;}
  public LocVM ChildLocations {get;set;}
```

}

So with query above

Any idea is welcome

Comment: The is a very vague question at best. Showing sample data and expected results will greatly help here, as we have more or less nothing to go on. You sound like you're describing a hierarchy within a single table and *maybe(?)* you want to query through that? If so, have you looked at using an rCTE? When you improve your question to help us understand your needs please do include your attempts as well.

Comment: @Larnu I have updated my question

Comment: You've given us sample data, but what about the rest that i asked for in my comment? What is your expected results? Where are you attempt(s)?

Comment: @Larnu I have made more simpler for u check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SampleData') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE SampleData

CREATE TABLE SampleData (ID int,ChildId INT,Name  VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO SampleData 
SELECT 1,null,'US'          UNION ALL
SELECT 2,null,'Canada'      UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1   ,'California'  UNION ALL
SELECT 4,3   ,'Los Angeles' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,2   ,'Nova Scotia' UNION ALL
SELECT 6,5   ,'Halifax'

SELECT * FROM SampleData
```

This Recursive CTE May be able to solve your requirement.

```
;With Cte
AS
(
SELECT 
     ID
     ,ChildId
    ,CAST('/'+Name AS nvarchar(1000)) AS [Heirarchy]
FROM SampleData
WHERE ChildId IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 
     e.ID
    ,e.ChildId
    ,CAST([Heirarchy]+'/'+e.Name AS nvarchar(1000)) AS [Heirarchy]
FROM SampleData e
INNER JOIN Cte t 
ON t.ID = e.ChildId
)
SELECT   ID
       ,RIGHT([Heirarchy],LEN([Heirarchy])-1) AS [CityHeirarchyPath]
FROM Cte
```

Result

```
ID  CityHeirarchyPath
----------------------
1   US
2   Canada
5   Canada/Nova Scotia
6   Canada/Nova Scotia/Halifax
3   US/California
4   US/California/Los Angeles
```

Comment: I am getting data in LInq query and its fine. I want to map my entity to View Model. Thats I was asking.   `modelVMobj=contaxt.Locations.select(w=>new LocVM{...what to do}).ToList()`